# Hide Birt Report Cross Tab cell

Tags: java, javascript

I am very new to Birt Tool,

I need to show/hide Summary field of the Cross Tab on the basis of some parameters which we can pass manually.
I used the **Properties-->Visibility --> show/hide element** but it only hide the data of the cell and blank cell are still showing and my need to disable the cell on the basis of some parameter.

I also tried by applying scripting on **OnPrepare event** but failed.

Kindly give me some suggestions...

Thanks in Advance.....